# List of all possible Uncaught Error: DOM Exceptions?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, domexception

After getting an "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8", and having seen a few others of the DOM Exceptions recently, I'm wondering...  Does anyone have a list of all possible DOM Exceptions, and what triggers each?  Seems like that'd be a godsend for debugging, instead of searching to try and decipher YANDE (Yet Another New DOM Exception) each time I run into a new one.

Comment: Just stumbled onto http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMException which lists Exceptions 1-15, but I'm pretty sure there's more, as I'm seeing at this moment questions on Stack Overflow about Exceptions 18 and 25...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a full list of possible `DOMException` types from the latest DOM spec, DOM4:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-dom-20120105/#domexception

It's a work in progress, and it seems 16-25 have been added since [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-17189187), the most recent completed spec that is fully implemented in browsers. [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-17189187) added types 16 and 17 but was never fully implemented in browsers.

Comment: Thanks - so many people getting errors, for once the W3 wasn't in the first few pages of my searches :P